# Why is VoiceOver on Mac 10.11 reading only the bracketed text in a label?

Tags: html, macos, accessibility, voiceover

When using VoiceOver on OS X in Safari, VoiceOver *seems* to be reading a label incorrectly:

```
<label for="investment-amount">Investment amount ($)</label>
<input type="text" name="investment" id="investment-amount">
```

VoiceOver will read, "dollar" on this field, and the cursor will highlight "$)".

Is this a problem with VoiceOver, or am I missing something related to labels and brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the issue. The labels were inside of a modal... When the modal fired, aria-hidden="true" was added to a parent element. This was causing bugs down the chain.

I'm still not sure why VoiceOver was reading a portion of the label, but taking off the aria-hidden caused the label to be read correctly.